# SpashScreen React Native

Tags: react-native, splash-screen, aws-amplify

So Im trying to create a splash screen for my react native app on android and I'm running into a problem where it seems its not able to SpashScreen.hide() due to my aws-amplify withAuthenticator. It just constantly stays on the splash screen

```
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(App);

class RealApp extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
     SplashScreen.hide();
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

  render() {

    return( 

        <AppContainer></AppContainer>
    );
  }
}

export default withAuthenticator(RealApp, {
  signUpConfig,
  usernameAttributes
});
```

With this it constantly stays on the SplashScreen Image. I then changed it around a little and got rid of the 'WithAuthenticator' like so:

```
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(App);

export default class RealApp extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
     SplashScreen.hide();
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

  render() {

    return( 

        <AppContainer></AppContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

That sort of worked in the sense it showed the SplashScreen then my Amplify Login Page but had the bottom Navbar already rendered with the Login page so could switch to different pages just the amplify login UI was still on the home page etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hide splash screen just navigate your self to another screen with setTimeout function

```
componentDidMount() {
    globalAny.isEditable = true;

    if (Constant.isIosDevice()) {
      if (CommonTask != undefined) {
        CommonTask.getStatusHeight((error: any, events: any) => {
          // console.log(events);
          Constant.setStatusHeight({
            top: events.top,
            bottom: events.bottom
          });
        });
      }
    } else {
      Constant.setStatusHeight({
        top: StatusBar.currentHeight,
        bottom: 0
      });
    }

    // AsyncStorage.setItem("defaultUserData","0");
    setTimeout(() => {
      this._token();
    }, 3000);
  }
```